# nativescript app size bigger than android app size

Tags: android, nativescript

I developed a simple nativescript app using blank template and vanilla javascript. When I build the app the size is about 12 MB. I did same app in android studio and the apk is about 2.5 MB which means 5 times smaller. I'm using latest version of nativescript and i used the CLI command.

```
tns build android --release --key-store-path petscrapbook.keystore --key-store-password petscrapbook --key-store-alias petscrapbook --key-store-alias-password petscrapbook
```

Have you got same issue?

Comment: what exactly is your question? non native solutions will always result in bigger app sizes I'd assume. I mean they are built on top of the native Framework.

Comment: @zanza67 For "I did same app in android studio" Is native android app..Right ??

Comment: That's normal when going for a framework that is not native.

Answer (score 6):

When I initially built by app, it was coming to around 40MB. Then with the below flags, I could get it under 15MB.

```
tns build android --bundle --env.uglify --env.aot --env.snapshot --release --key-store-path <path-to-your-keystore> --key-store-password <your-key-store-password> --key-store-alias <your-alias-name> --key-store-alias-password <your-alias-password> --aab --copy-to <android-app-bundle-path>.aab
```

You can see the details about these flags here: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/performance-optimizations/startup-times

The last flag --aab, is for building Android App Bundle, instead of apk. Refer: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/publishing/android-app-bundle

You may not get size as small as pure android, but this is definitely better than without these flags.

Comment: I tried everything, the exact command what you used. my app size reduce from 43 mb to 36 mb that's all. i don't know the reason. even i raised a question on official github also. And no one answering why my app size is big. I don't have images videos in my app. nor any hardcoded string values.

Comment: If you have uploaded the app to google play store, you can check app download size breakdown in Google Play Console > Android vitals > App size, this gives a fair idea what is taking up more size.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any issue at all. That's pretty normal

Answer (score 1):

Native-script works with node_modules and while building app, it's dependency are added in build and that's the reason for increasing size of native-script android and ios app.

Comment: thanks Jay but i put in the backet that non native app can be bigger compare to native app but not with this dimension. if just building hello world app is 5 times bigger what about a professional app??? this is not acceptable. nobody will develop professional app with such big differences in term of sizing. do you agree?

Comment: Ya. But still client required that because it will develop android and ios at the same time with single developer. And not with each new file size will multiple *5 ..

Comment: i cannot propose to my boss such difference, he will go out for sure from this path even if i can agree with you about 1 framework for 2 platform. we need performance and keep size small

Comment: @zanza67
Yes, It's totally based on different criteria, requirement and performance required from client end. For general scenario we do prefer different native apps. But as per current situation native-script is acquiring market. 
If you think answer is helpful then you can approve and upvote so other can get the better idea from discussion.

Comment: thanks jay for you helpful answer. i know that we cannot expect same code, size, performance, optimization using a framework compare to native app but at least i would assume that i can manage the differences applying some tips and tricks for example, but if the difference is so large from the basis, i doubt that it will gain more market. ionic and corbova went down for this reason becasue the advantages were less than the advantages. it is totally true that it is easier to maintain code, you have javascript, angular, vuejs, but on the other side native apps are still the best option

Answer (score 1):

According to the Nativescript blog (https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-android-application-package-size-revealed), this is normal unfortunately:

> In order for a NativeScript Android application to be available on devices with different binary interfaces, the NativeScript Android Runtime package has to provide the correct ABI versions for its native libraries.
>
> The most common ABIs nowadays are: x86, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a.
>
> **Blank NativeScript projects for Android are ~12MB by default** because they include three copies of the NativeScript runtime built for different Android CPU architectures.